# Cannot Login Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login, gedit

I have been using Ubuntu for 2 months and it work fine. Yesterday I tried to make my Texlive Manager (tlmgr) running by inserting a `PATH` in `/etc/profile.d`.

Today when I wanted to login as usual, I cannot login.

I tried the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and login through `tty1`. Yes, I could login. The shell is there. However, when I wanted to open the `/etc/profile.d` to delete whatever I inserted, I could not open the file. I tried `gedit` command but the error is like this:

```
gedit is available in /usr/bin/gedit
gedit : command not found.
```

Can anyone help me. There are so many questions regarding this matter but I do not know which answer is relevant with my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `tty1` you cannot to edit a file with `gedit`. Use `vi` for example:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/[file]
```

where `[file]` is the name of the file that you edited (it cannot be `/etc/profile.d` because this is a directory).

And I think that you should reset your `PATH` to default (because of `gedit : command not found.`):

```
export PATH='/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games'
```

Other thing that you can do is when you are in `tty1` to run this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/
```

You can replace `$USER` with your actual username.

Try logging in again.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot run the vi command either. Even ls command too. But I didn't try to do the export PATH....Let me try first.

Comment: @wahidahhashim Reset your PATH and after it will work.

Comment: Follow the above command is it? OK..I'll do it now..TQ

Comment: OK...I can open my nano :) but..I couldn't find the file that I want to open. Yesterday, I would like to make my tlmgr working. So, I followed an instruction to insert PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64_linux:$PATH but now I couldn't remember where I inserted it.

Comment: @wahidahhashim Most probably could be `.profile` file (`/home/$USER/.profile` )

Comment: I found it in /etc/environment. Deleted the added PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64_linux:$PATH. However, it seems that's not the problem because I still could not login as usual through GUI. After entered password, the screen became black just a second and have to login again. What to do now? Tq.

Comment: Hi @wahidah-hashim, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @wahidahhashim I just edited my answer, try with this

Comment: Sorry, which answer Mr.Radu? I thought on trying the command sudo rm ./.Xauthority that you suggested in other link.

Comment: @wahidahhashim Try this command `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/` and after `sudo reboot`

Comment: Hi! Sorry to say, it's not working. I tried sudo rm ./.Xauthority and also sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/. I also tried to sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu desktop. The result still the same. I could not login through GUI. After insert password and enter, the screen blank black for a second and login interface appeared again. Any other solution?

Comment: I also tried a suggestion from a link: ctrl-alt-f2 then sudo chown user:user .Xauthority  NOT WORKING too....:(   Could it be because of different Ubuntu version?

Comment: @wahidahhashim [desktop login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140652/12-04-desktop-login-loop)

Comment: Final step I think...I followed the link...$ecryptfs-mount-private and also $sudo apt-get install gnome-session fallback. I got error on the gnome-session. I also tried from other link....sudo pstree, sudo apt-get install gdm, sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm.....ALL NOT WORKING...I am thinking to stop using Ubuntu...looking for Cygwin instead...Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Uninstall and re-install Ubuntu...is it the last choice I have?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `profile.d` is a directory, and you can't edit a directory.  The file that you edited is inside that directory.

So try this.  When you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and log in, do:

```
nano
```

When the editor opens, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and type the path like this:

```
/etc/profile.d/file_name
```

Comment: I think that you have forgotten to included the output:)

Comment: Thank you. After login, the output is -bash: groups: command not found Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname' The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable......etc....and finally appeared wahidahusm@wahidah:~$       When I type nano, the output is: Command 'nano' is available in the following place */bin/nano and */usr/bin/nano  The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.   Why is this happened?

Comment: It happened because its not in your path statement.  You can use full path as so: `/usr/bin/nano`, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, login through `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), then type this at the prompt:

```
sudo /usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc
```

When it opens up, press <kbd>i</kbd>. Press enter to insert a line, then press up to go to the empty line. In this empty line you just inserted, type in the following:

```
export PATH='/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64_linux'
```

After you type it, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (capital Z twice). This should close and save the file, and bring you back to the tty prompt.

Restart your machine.

Comment: Hi! Tq. I found the file and edited already but it seems not affecting the login through GUI. Now I found an answer from other link, I would like to try the sudo rm ./.Xauthority  Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could go ahead. I found two other questions that have the same answer, which is to `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority` (the two questions are http://askubuntu.com/q/129246/52726 and http://askubuntu.com/q/130153/52726).

Comment: Hi AlaaAli. I tried the above recommendation. Unfortunately..failed to login as usual...Thank you for your support.